# Search documents which has specific column in mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

```
db.posts.insert({
    title: "Hello World",
    "2d": [1,2],
    "3d": [3,4,5],
    "4d": [6,7,8,9],
    "6d: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
});
```

Each document can have only the `2d` column, or just the `3d` column, or just the both, or just `4d` and `2d`, etc. How do I find documents which has that specific column?

`SELECT * FROM posts where posts.hascolumn=2d`

^Just for demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `db.posts.find({"2d" : {$exists:true})`

Comment: Ha1 magical. Thanks mate, where in the docs can I find this? BTW u lacked one `}`

Comment: You can find it in Advanced queries section
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists